# Do we have a limit number of interfaces which we can impliment to an object? (in Java)

Tags: java, oop, interface, implementation

Do we have a limit number of interfaces which we can impliment to an object? 
If we do, then how many?

Comment: How many interfaces do you want to implement? Where is this question coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of direct superinterfaces of a class or interface is limited to 65535 by the size of the interfaces_count item of the ClassFile structure.